# OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred - after changing app namespace

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth, action, facebook-opengraph

we had a working facebook app with an own action that has been reviewed and been approved by facebook. Everything worked fine.

After changing the namespace and the title of the app, we now get an an error when sending the action via php sdk, althought all the action is still marked as approved and live.

```
$response = $facebook->api(
      'me/myapp:create',
      'POST', array('custom_object' => "http://www.myapp.com/metatags.php") );
```

This is the error we receive:

> OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

We've' already checked if the access token is vaild, it is!

Is it possible that facebook needs to re-approve custom actions after changing the namespace? Or does it need some time until it works again?

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this today, however my experience was in JavaScript, so I don't have relevant code to provide, you should be able to apply the same theory!

It seems that the error only happens once per access request - if you try to post again immediately after, it will usually be accepted by facebook with no error. Since the error code returned for unknown error is always the same, you can simply catch the error code from the response object and run the function again if it matches.